# Unable to login to prestashop admin after full package installation

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I purchased a PrestaShop gomarket theme and I installed the full package on my local machine with XAMPP according to a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZU4kWiUdkE0. Now the front office is functioning perfectly. But I want to know how to login to the back office. Usually inside the package folder there should be a admin folder but there is not. Is there any way to install admin panel?

Comment: Did you check if there is any folder starting with name "admin"?

Comment: He's not accessing the back office in this video but your main folder contains folder with "admin" + "unique_combination" like 7890 which is mentioned in the docs http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Connecting+to+the+PrestaShop+back-office.

Answer (score 1):

In the video there is a folder psadmin. So hopefully it's the same for you too.
To connect use this url: http://yoursite.com/psadmin or http://localhost/yoursite/psadmin

For security reasons when you install prestashop it asks you to change the admin folder into something else.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the name of the folder. I missed it for the first time. Probably you're right and the answer is `psadmin`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your htdocs and then find folder with the name like "adminXXX", where XXX contains unique combination which is created automatically. If you are using older version than 1.5.4, you have rename it manually.

As **Catalin Scaesteanu** mentioned to you already, the only "custom" folder name is `psadmin`.

[image]
Check the docs:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Connecting+to+the+PrestaShop+back-office

> The PrestaShop back-office is the name used to describe the
>   administration panel of your PrestaShop site in this user-guide. You
>   will spend most of your time in this panel, as everything that the
>   user sees is handled directly through the back-office:
>   adding/editing/removing products, handling carriers, building packs,
>   creating vouchers, keeping contact with customers, improving your
>   shop, etc. During the install process, the /admin folder is renamed
>   into something unique to your shop (for instance, /admin7890), for
>   security reasons. Use that new folder name to access your shop (for
>   example: http://myprestashop.com/admin7890). Up to version 1.5.3, you
>   had to manually rename the /admin folder into something unique to you.
>   Since version 1.5.4, this is done automatically by PrestaShop. Be
>   careful to memorize that folder name the first time you access it
>   after the installation! You will see the login page for your shop's
>   control panel.

If you are not sure about the demo account you may check the image below. In this case it's demo@presthemes.com/presthemes.
[image]